# what is the poison in chinaberry?

Tags: biochemistry, botany, trees, poison, invasive-species

I was trying to look up what the poison in Chinaberry is, however, with the exception of a couple related compounds was able to find no information on the poison. What chemical makes up the Chinaberry poison, and what is this chemical's concentration and LD50, if known?

Edit: The Chinaberry I am referring to is *Melia azedarach*

Comment: Which chinaberry do you mean? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinaberry_(disambiguation)

Comment: @jamesqf I am referring to *Melia azedarach*, I was not aware that there are multiple plants by that name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The toxin is Meliatoxin, in a class of toxins called tetranortriterpenes.

I found this here.  Bold emphasis mine.

https://wagwalking.com/condition/chinaberry-tree-poisoning

> What is Chinaberry Poisoning? The chinaberry tree is a member of the
> mahogany family that is native to Australia, China, and India. These
> deciduous trees sprout delicate light purple flowers in the spring,
> which develop into yellow, berry-like fruits in the summer. They were
> transported to North America in the early 1800’s as an ornamental
> plant, but has escaped into the environment and is considered an
> invasive species in several southern states. It produces a potent
> insecticide which **utilizes a tetranortriterpene neurotoxin known as
> meliatoxin.** This insecticide is found throughout the plant’s bark,
> leaves, and flowers but is found in the highest concentrations in the
> ripe fruit. If you suspect that your pet has consumed any of this
> plant, contact your veterinarian immediately. The chinaberry tree, or
> Melia azedarach, is a deciduous tree that produces a potent
> insecticide which utilizes a neurotoxin that can prove detrimental to
> your pet if ingested. Symptoms of Chinaberry Poisoning in Dogs
> Symptoms of chinaberry tree poisoning occur most often from eating the
> ripe fruit, however, the bark, leaves, and flowers also contain
> smaller amounts of the toxic substances. Symptoms usually begin within
> just two to four hours from ingestion. Abdominal pain Blood in stool
> Colic Constipation Death Depression Diarrhea         Excessive
> drooling Heart attack Hyperactivity Lack of coordination Loss of
> appetite Muscle rigidity Seizures Slowed heart rate Stupor Vomiting
> Weakness Types
>
> The scientific name for the chinaberry tree is Melia
> azedarach, and it belongs in the mahogany family.

From another source
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0031942283830398

> Toxic tetranortriterpenes of the fruit of Melia azedarach . .Peter >B.Oelrichs. Michael W.Hill. Peter J.Vallely. John K.MacLeod. .Tadeusz >F.Molinski
> Show more https://doi.org/10.1016/0031-9422(83)83039-8Get rights and
> content Abstract Four new tetranortriterpenes, meliatoxins A1, A2, B1
> and B2 have been isolated and identified as toxic constituents of the
> fruit of Melia azedarach L. var. australasica. Toxicity and
> pathological results confirm that the meliatoxins are responsible for
> most but not all of the symptoms resulting from the ingestion of whole
> fruit.